# Button click is not working properly in jellybean

Tags: android

I am taking text from edittext and performing some calculation of the values which works in every api version except JellyBean. The problem is when I put a number in edit text and press the calculate button it works then when I change the value of that edittext to something else and press calculate again it doesnt work. I need to restart the application to work with it. I dont have any jellybean device to test but my client provided me a video and I saw that this fact is true. What should I do now?

Here is my calculation code that I did in that button clicklistener

```
try {
                double i = Double.parseDouble(startdate.getText().toString()) / 365;
                double j = 1 / i;
                double k = Math.pow(d3, j);
                double l = k - 1;
                double m = l * 100;
                annualroi = roundTwoDecimals(m);
                investmentyear.setText("Investment periode(Days):"
                        + startdate.getText().toString());

                annualizeroi.setText("Simple Annualized ROI(%):" + annualroi);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

here is my actual activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText originalinvestment, returnedvalue, startdate;
    Button startpick, endpick, calculate, calculateannual;
    String posstartdate, postenddate;
    static final int DATE_PICKER_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    static final int DATE_PICKER_DIALOG_IDTWO = 1;
    Date dayofyearone;
    Date dayofyeartwo;
    double d1;
    double d;
    double d2;
    double d3;
    TextView tgainorloss, investmentyear, returninvestment, annualizeroi;
    double year;
    double gainorloss;
    double roi;
    double annualroi;
    int k1;
    int l1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        // getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializer();

        calculate.setOnClickListener(this);
        calculateannual.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void initializer() {

        originalinvestment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etoriginalinvestment);
        returnedvalue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etreturnedvalue);
        startdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etstartdate);

        calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncalculate);
        tgainorloss = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtgainorloss);
        investmentyear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtinvestmentterm);
        returninvestment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtreturninvest);
        annualizeroi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtannualizeroi);
        calculateannual = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncalculateannual);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btncalculate:
            getYearDifference();

            break;

        case R.id.btncalculateannual:
            try {
                double i = Double.parseDouble(startdate.getText().toString()) / 365;
                double j = 1 / i;
                double k = Math.pow(d3, j);
                double l = k - 1;
                double m = l * 100;
                annualroi = roundTwoDecimals(m);
                investmentyear.setText("Investment periode(Days):"
                        + startdate.getText().toString());

                annualizeroi.setText("Simple Annualized ROI(%):" + annualroi);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }

    }

    double roundTwoDecimals(double d) {
        return Double.valueOf((new DecimalFormat("#.##")).format(d))
                .doubleValue();
    }

    public void getYearDifference() {
        try {

            if (!originalinvestment.getText().toString().contentEquals("")
                    && !returnedvalue.getText().toString().contentEquals("")) {

                d = Double.parseDouble(originalinvestment.getText().toString());
                d1 = roundTwoDecimals(Double.parseDouble(returnedvalue
                        .getText().toString()) - d);

                gainorloss = d1;
                roi = roundTwoDecimals(100D * (d1 / d));
                d3 = (roi / 100) + 1;

                tgainorloss.setText("Gain or loss investment($):" + gainorloss);
                returninvestment.setText("Return on Investment(%):" + roi);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Post your actual Activity code..

Comment: You are using variable names with numerations, i, j, k, l, m, d, d1, d2, d3, k1, l1.... and you expect us to find your issues? Please some books about clean code...

Comment: And do you have any idea of which error occures?

Comment: There is no problem in variables, please first read carefully my question, everything is working fine in the other versions. U can avoid those variables. Warren

No the client couldn't give me the error msg Martijn

Comment: tye with ur jelly bean emulator and check what is the problem